# ExternalAccessory - Behaviour of touches on external screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, touchscreen, external-accessory

I am about to receive a task in my company and I want to be ready before it lands on my desk. I searched on the net about the questions I have but couldn’t find proper answers.

So, here is the requirement, I have to communicate to an external device having touch screen using bluetooth or lightning cable. I will be using ExternalAccessory.framework as the device is registered under Apple’s MFI program. Here, external device screen will act as a secondary display for my iOS application.

Now, the part I am unaware of is, when the secondary screen is touched by the user (let’s say pan gesture),  how the screen will behave? Will the external screen update automatically? If not, what are the alternatives?

Note: I can not fake the touch as we are targeting the app to the app-store.